# FFMPEG Generate N Evenly Spaced PNG Screenshots

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to generate 8 screenshots for an uploaded video using FFMPEG. I currently have:

> ffmpeg -i Trailer-720p.mov -r .2
>   -vcodec png Preview-%d.png

Which generates a screenshot every 5 seconds. How can I add the ability to generate a screenshot for frames distributed over a percentage of total time. Thanks. Furthermore, is it possible to generate a screenshot at 50% for example? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run ffmpeg with just the -i parameter, it will provide you with the length of the video on stderr (among lots of other things). You could write something around that, converting the duration and the intended number of frames into the correct -r parameter.

Here is an quick example in python which basically does what I have described. For some reason the first two stills generated by my version of ffmpeg both show frame 0, but Preview-3 to Preview-n are in the correct intervals. Run it with the second parameter set to '1' and it will generate the middle frame as Preview-3.png.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys,os,re
from subprocess import *

if len(sys.argv)<=1:
  print("usage: python oneinn.py filename frames")
  sys.exit(0)

try:
  fvideo = sys.argv[1]
  frames = float(sys.argv[2])
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Failed to parse parameters.\n")
  sys.exit(1)

output = Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", fvideo], stderr=PIPE).communicate()

# searching and parsing "Duration: 00:05:24.13," from ffmpeg stderr, ignoring the centiseconds
re_duration = re.compile("Duration: (.*?)\.")
duration = re_duration.search(output[1]).groups()[0]

seconds = reduce(lambda x,y:x*60+y,map(int,duration.split(":")))
rate = frames/seconds

print("Duration = %s (%i seconds)" % (duration, seconds))
print("Capturing one frame every %.1f seconds" % (1/rate))

output = Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", fvideo, "-r", str(rate), "-vcodec", "png", 'Preview-%d.png']).communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do it all in FFMPEG (I am using external service that does not allow scripting), but I do appreciate the answer.

Comment: Add parentheses after your print call to make it python3 compatible.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Doesn't work ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/torrents/uploads/Dahil Mahal Kita - The Dolzura Cortez Story (1993)/shot.py", line 21, in <module>
    duration = re_duration.search(output[1]).groups()[0]
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object```

Answer (score 12):

Or just with a shell command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4v -vf fps=1/$(echo 'scale=6;' $(ffprobe -loglevel \
    quiet -of 'compact=nokey=1:print_section=0' -show_format_entry \
    duration input.m4v) ' / 10' | bc) -vframes 10 -qscale:v 2 \
    thumbnail-%d.png
```

This creates 10 thumbnails with the same dimensions as the source video.

Comment: brilliant. bc calculates the fps seconds, using ffprobe. `scale=6` is the number of digits used in that number. `qscale:v` is the variable bit rate, set to 2. I dont know why the `vframes 10` is in there.

Comment: The video filter with the FPS (1 / frame interval) should result in a stream with exactly the correct number of frames, but sometimes we're off by one because of rounding. The -vframes hard-limits the number of frames (i.e. sometimes dropping the last frame).

Answer (score 3):

### Here's one in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# pass the video source file(s) into the command line args
# resulting images are jpg, just change the appropriate ffmpeg option for png.
# the last line uses ImageMagick to stitch the images together into a strip.    
# the first image is thrown away, since it's a duplicate of the second image.

ARGV.each do|a|
  total_shots = 4
  size = '200x200'
  meta = %x(ffmpeg -i #{a} 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//)
  time_parts = meta.match /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\.(\d\d)/
  duration_seconds = time_parts[1].to_i*60*60+time_parts[2].to_i*60+time_parts[3].to_i+time_parts[4].to_f/100
  puts "*** Duration seconds: " +  duration_seconds.to_s
  %x(ffmpeg -i #{a} -r #{total_shots/duration_seconds} -s #{size} -f image2 -vframes #{total_shots+1} foo-%03d.jpg )
  files = (1..total_shots+1).map{|i| 'foo-' + ("%03d" % i) + '.jpg'}
  files.delete_at 0
  %x(convert -append #{files.join ' '} shot-strip.jpg)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not get Manfred Stienstra's brilliant oneliner to generate frames at the exact right spot. If I specified to generate 8 images from a 240 secs movie, the first one would be 15, the second at 45, etcetera. I wanted the first one to be 0, the second at 30, etcetera.

So I took his oneliner apart and created this

```
ffmpeg=../bin/ffmpeg
ffprobe=../bin/ffprobe
outdir=../test
infile=../testmovie.mp4
outbase=testmovie

steps=8

len=`$ffprobe -loglevel quiet -of 'compact=nokey=1:print_section=0' -show_format_entry duration $infile`
echo length $len

secs=`echo 'scale=6;' $len ' /  ' $steps | bc`
echo secs $secs

for ((i=0; i <= $steps ; i++)); do
    echo =========================
    echo $ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 \
            -i $infile -f image2 -ss `echo $secs \* $i | bc` \
             -vframes 1 "$outdir/$outbase"-$i.jpg
    $ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 \
            -i $infile -f image2 -ss `echo $secs \* $i | bc`  \
             -vframes 1 "$outdir/$outbase"-$i.jpg
done
```

Comment: Correct, I'm skipping the first frame intentionally. In my experience this frame is usually not very interesting because it's black, the start of a title screen, or someone setting up for a presentation, etc. In our software we also default to the third thumbnail because that's usually where the action happens.