# Grocery CRUD multiple upload field

Tags: php, codeigniter, video-thumbnails, grocery-crud

I am working on the admin section of a website in codeigniter. I am using Grocery CRUD for the
add edit delete operations. I've used 'set_field_upload' function to provide a video upload field inside the form. I need to add a thumbnail for the video, so require another upload field. 
Is it possible to implement multiple upload field inside the form using grocery crud? Are there any other methods to create thumbnail other than ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend invoking `ffmpeg` on the server once the upload is complete using PHP's `exec()`. Have a look at these SE answers for some ideas:

- [FFMPEG Generate N Evenly Spaced PNG Screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306888/ffmpeg-generate-n-evenly-spaced-png-screenshots)
- [Video Thumbnails using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/135806/video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg)

Temporarily store the images generated by `ffmpeg`, echo their paths back to the client using AJAX and have them select the one they wish.